# How to display A B C D E if a input 5 numbers 1 2 3 4 5

Tags: python, random

```py
import random
ltr =" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
print(ltr.strip())
a = input('')
b = input('')
c = input('')
d = input('')
e = input('')
print(a,b,c,d,e)
var1 = random.randrange(1,26)
var2 = random.randrange(1,26)
var3 = random.randrange(1,26)
var4 = random.randrange(1,26)
var5 = random.randrange(1,26)
print(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)
```

What I want to do is when I input numbers from 1 to 26 it should display a corresponding result. As you can see, the user must input 5 numbers. For example, if we input 1 2 3 4 5 the result must be A B C D E. Also, we have random numbers. For example, if our random numbers are 4 5 3 1 2 the result must be D E C A B.
I don't know what to do to display the result.

Comment: change use of `random.randrange` to `var1 = ltr[a]`, and repeat for each variable

Comment: i can't sir it is part of the code the given must 10 numbers in total 5 user input and 5 random numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
random.randrange(1,26)
```

This is wrong. Random's second parameter is non-inclusive, meaning you'll get numbers from 1 to 25.

You should use:

```
random.randrange(1, len(ltr))
```

Then your result letter is just accessing the correct index in your `ltr` string - simply doing `ltr(var1)`

---

As for user input, you need to invert it to integer values like this:

```
a = int(input(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to print the letter in the alphabet which is at the position the user entered. In other words, the user enters the `index` of that letter inside the alphabet. Since you can access a character inside a string using its index in python using `letter = string[index]` you can do this:

```
ltr =" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

a = input('')
b = input('')
c = input('')
d = input('')
e = input('')
print(a,b,c,d,e)
print(ltr[a], ltr[b], ltr[c], ltr[d], ltr[e])
```

Note that due to the space at the start of `ltr`, `A` will be output when entering `1`.

**Edit:** Update according to question in comments.
You can sort the inputs if you put them in a list and `sort()` them. Then you can get the characters at the positions from the input list:

```
ltr =" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

inputs = []
for _ in range(5):
    inputs.append(int(input("Enter a number:")))

inputs.sort()
print(', '.join(map(str, inputs)))
print(', '.join(ltr[i] for i in inputs))
```

Comment: convert string to int ?

Comment: In this case it is done implicitly and not necessary but you are right it would be good to have this explicit.

Comment: i intetionally put a space to start the count to 1

Comment: my program is when i enter numbers from 1 to 26 it will display the corresponding letters

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what it does?

Comment: sir can i ask you how to sort numbers from lowest to highest?

Answer (score 0):

strip() your ltr and find element at (entered_position-1) , repeat for five times ,and join the list separated by a space

```
ltr = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
print(' '.join([ltr.strip()[int(input('number 1-26: '))-1] for _ in range(5)]))
print(' '.join([ltr.strip()[random.randrange(1,27)-1] for _ in range(5)]))
```